# Unable to print ADO User Stories

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ado, user-stories

I tried to print the ADO user stories form that icon where the red circle is. I am unable to print and giving the below error. I tried different boards in different projects and same for all the boards.

Couldn't find any solution for this. Can you please help me. Thanks

[image]

Installed Extensions;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, it seems that you are using the Prints cards feature from extensions: [Print Cards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.PrintCards) or [Agile Cards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spartez.agile-cards).

Currently these extensions have been deprecated. It is no longer maintained by the developers.

Therefore there will be issues or limitations in its functionality. The could be the cause of the issue.

I suggest that you can uninstall the old extension and change to use other Print Cards extensions in Marketplace to Print the cards in Azure Borads.

For example:

[Print Physical Card](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OneLuckiDev.ppcards)

[Other Print Cards extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=print%20cards&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Boards&sortBy=Relevance)

**Update:**

From the extension list, there are two print work item extension: [Boards cards for printing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NickMyers.board-cards) and [Work item Print](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrtarantula.wiprint). Their printing capabilities don't match what you circled in the error picture.

For work item print extension, you can print work items in Query or Work item.

For example:

[image]

For Boards cards for printing extension, you can print work items in **Sprints -> Print** tab.

For example:

[image]

The error feature circled in the screenshot of the question may still be caused by extension deprecation.

To meet your requirements to print user stories, you can refer to the following steps:

Step1: Setup the Print details in **Boards -> Work item Print** tab.

Step2: Create work item query in **Boards -> Queries** and use Print Option to print the work items in bulk.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I have update the post with installed printing extensions list. Is there any issues with one of them or I thought this error because, there was an iteration that had been deleted (as per the screenshot).

Comment: @KalanaD From your screenshot of the extensions, there are two print work item extension: Boards cards for printing and Work item Print. Their printing capabilities don't match what you circled in the error picture. I have update the answer to share more details, you can check it.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, really appreciate your explanation and the support. I found the issue and yes you are correct. The issue caused by extension deprecation. There was an another extension called "Agile Cards". It has been unpublished from Marketplace. I remove that and your solution that provided above will do the work. Thanks a lot again.